# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastai.vision'

Tags: deep-learning, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I am trying to use `ImageDataBunch` from fastai, and it worked fine, but recently when I ran my code, it showed this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fastai.vision'`

Then, I upgraded my fastai version `pip install fastai --upgrade`. This error got cleared but landed in `NameError: name 'ImageDataBunch' is not defined`

Here's my code:

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
from fastai.vision import *
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module="torch.nn.functional")
np.random.seed(42)
data = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path, train='.', valid_pct=0.2, 
                                  ds_tfms=get_transforms(), size=224, num_workers=4, no_check=True).normalize(imagenet_stats)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

I actually ran into this same issue when I started using Colab, but haven't been able to reproduce it. Here was the thread describing what I and another developer did to troubleshoot: https://forums.fast.ai/t/no-module-named-fastai-data-in-google-colab/78164/4

I would recommend trying to factory reset your runtime ( "Runtime" -> "Factory Reset Runtime")

Then you can check which version of fastai you have (you have to restart the runtime to use the new version if you've already imported it)

```
import fastai
fastai.__version__
```

I'm able to run `fastai.vision import *` on fastai version 1.0.61 and 2.0.13

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about ImageDataBunch and after trying your's solution I got fastai version to be ```2.0.13``` but still I am facing ImageDataBunch error? Does fastai upgraded version supports it or not,  how to fix that?

Comment: Factory Reset Runtime as you recommended did fix it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Google Colab:

Upgrade fastai on colab:

```
! [ -e /content ] && pip install -Uqq fastai
```

Import necessary libraries:

```
from fastai.vision.all import *
from fastai.text.all import *
from fastai.collab import *
from fastai.tabular.all import *
```

Get the images and annotations:

```
path = untar_data(URLs.PETS)
path_anno = path/'annotations'
path_img = path/'images'
print( path_img.ls() )             # print all images
fnames = get_image_files(path_img) # -->> 7390 images
print(fnames[:5])                  # print first 5 images
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is to copy to (connect) my google drive & then run the cells. [Source](https://www.joehxblog.com/fast.ia-modulenotfounderror-in-google-colab/)

[image: Click on "Copy to Drive"]

Answer (score 0):

You might have installed the older version of `fastai`. You need to upgrade to `fastaiv2`. You can upgrade fastai by using pip as shown below.

```
!pip install fastai --upgrade
```

Also check your `fastai` version using

```
import fastai
print(fastai.__version__)
```